# Use Shiny to serve images reactively

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I need to somehow serve R images reactively to a system that only lets me use a subset of HTML, so no iframes. Basically, it will have to be something like `img src="https://shinyserver.com/app/image123.jpeg" /'.

I am thinking about using https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.router, but not sure if it will work.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "R images"? Are these plots generated by R? Does the HTML subset allow entire img-tags, or just the image's url?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if that really addresses your problem, but since you mentioned `shiny.router`, I think the `plumber` package might also be useful.

This is a small example, that lets you create an image tag using an R function as API.

**plumber.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(plumber)

#' Get an image tag with source from its name
#' @param imgsrc Source of the image
#' @get /
img2tag <- function(imgsrc = "") {
  url = paste0('https://shinyserver.com/app/', imgsrc)
  as.character(tags$img(src=url))
}
```

Then you have to start the plumber API by entering:

```
pr <- plumber::plumb("plumber.R")
pr$run(port = 7818)
```

And then you can access it in the browser via:

```
http://localhost:7818/?imgsrc=image123.jpeg
```

which gives you the JSON-aquivalent of the string:

```
0   "<img src=\"https://shinyserver.com/app/image123.jpeg\"/>"
```

or through the console with:

```
curl http://localhost:7818/?imgsrc=image123.jpeg
```